# Running Socket.io on Azure with fallback to FlashSockets

Tags: azure, socket.io

I'm attempting to run socket.io on Azure with a fallback to FlashSockets in IE9. The app works using websockets in FF and Chrome, but when Socket.IO attempts to use the Flash fallback in IE9, I receive the following error.

> [WebSocket] cannot connect to Web Socket server at > > ws://example.cloudapp.net:80/socket.io/1/flashsocket/19127550151689645722 (SecurityError)
>   make sure the server is running and Flash socket policy file is correctly placed

Socket.io is running on the server because I can access the the /socket.io/socket.io.js client file. IE9 also successfully grabs the SWF file that it should be requesting.

I'm assuming by the error message that the issue has to do with the port not being available. I haven't been able to access the crossdomain.xml file using port :10843, which is Socket.io's default port and where I think I would find it. This all also works locally in the Azure emulator. Any guidance on how to configure the port in Azure or how to find/test the crossdomain.xml file would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is just that port 10843 isn't open, I think all you need to do is add `<InputEndpoint protocol="tcp" port="10843" />` to your `.csdef` file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but it didn't seem to work. I tried HTTP instead of TCP, since I thought that's what socket.io might be looking for in the case of the crossdomain file. Was there any reason you chose TCP or was it just an example?

Comment: TCP was what socket.io was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: TCP vs. HTTP is a bit confusing in Windows Azure. TCP really means "anything TCP-based" (which includes HTTP). HTTP really means "anything you want http.sys, a Windows component used by IIS, to use." So if you use HTTP, you often can't actually bind to that port, because http.sys is already connected to it. You want HTTP for IIS (and a few other Windows-y uses) but TCP for everything else.